# Get data of child table from parent table in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Orders Table, to migration data

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TableId { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public Table Table { get; set; }
}
```

Tables table, to migration data

```
public class Table
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Order configuration

```
    public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Orders");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.TableId).IsRequired(false);

            builder.HasOne(x => x.Table).WithMany(x => x.Orders).HasForeignKey(x => x.TableId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
    }
```

Table configuration

```
    public class TableConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Table>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Table> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Tables");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();

            builder.HasMany(x => x.Orders).WithOne(x => x.Table).HasForeignKey(x => x.TableId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
    }
```

I added all of above to SampleDbContext.cs like:

```
public class SampleDbContext: DbContext
{
    public SampleDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TableConfiguration());
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

And order view model

```
public class OrderVm
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string TableId { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a order service to get list all orders

```
private readonly UOrderDbContext _context;

public OrderService(UOrderDbContext dbContext)
{
      _context = dbContext;
}
public async Task<List<OrderVm>> GetAllOrder()
{
    var list = await _context.Orders.ToListAsync();
    return list.Select(p => new OrderVm()
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Total = p.Total,
        TableId = p.TableId,
        TableName = p.Table.Name,//error line
    }).ToList();
}
```

I tried, but the result is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can not get name of table when getting all orders, instead it is *null*.

Comment: make sure `_context` is not null, also, you can preload (eager load) the `Children` while loading `Parent` using [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager). please do check the docs for caveats.

Comment: What's the actual code where the exception was thrown? Is `_context` null perhaps? Where do you create the DbContext instance?

Comment: Post the code in the question itself. Although I start to suspect you're using the "repository over ORM" antipattern, and haven't registered the DbContext properly. PS there are no classes in that folder

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just updated